# Using KeyHash signature as a post parameter on a secure SSL connection

Tags: java, android, security, signature

In my app I have two types of contents: Free and in-app products.
I get free products information through a plain http connection but for in-app products I use httpS and as a POST parameter, each time I generate KeyHash from below method and check it on my server with the one I got from the same method in log prints before removing my app logs.

I know that debug signed APKs and release signed ones, produce different KeyHash and I use the correct one from released APK.

I have these assumptions about the KeyHash and I really wanted to be sure that my assumptions are correct before releasing my app into the wild.

1-  No one can generate the same KeyHash if they unpack and decompile my APK classes because for generating the same KeyHash they need my certificate key that they do not possess.
Except by those brute force methods which is not practical.

2-  This KeyHash is not going to change by changing the class names or packages or adding new ones in the future if I update my app. I tested this and each time I got the same KeyHash signature.

3-  There is no other known way for attackers to find  out this KeyHash.

I have to say I’m a little confused by all this certificate and signature stuff and I’m not sure what is the relation between this generated KeyHash signature and my certificate for signing the apk or with package structure of the apk.
I’ll appreciate if someone tell me what is this KeyHash exactly too.

---

EDITED (for clarifying) : My goal is to protect my products. I don't want anyone can access them by knowing my URL's POST parameter if they decompile my classes. so instead of putting the post parameter in a String, I get it from that method.

---

The method for generating the KeyHash:

```
public String validateAppSignature(Context context) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        String currentSignature = "";
        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {
            byte[] signatureBytes = signature.toByteArray();
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            currentSignature = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);

            Log.d("REMOVED_LOG", "\n" + currentSignature);
        }

        return currentSignature;
    }
```

Also about my httpS connetion, for now, I use my self-signed certificate for my server’s httpS and I put the BKS version of my certificate inside the raw folder for Java’s “HttpsURLConnection” to accept.
Does my app have a major security weakness because of using SSL self-signed certificate?

Comment: Its unclear which part of the application you are trying to protect. But it also resembles security thru obscurity, which is no security at all. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Comment: @muttonUp  I protect my products which I get their information from my server. I want no one can access those information by knowing my url's POST parameter if they decompile my classes. so instead of putting the post parameter in a String, I get it from that method

Comment: This is not security thru obscurity at all.